# Order 'Contain' Model in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: model, cakephp-3.x, contain

I have multiple `Things` in `AnotherThing` now I am trying to order them in my edit action in my `AnotherThing Controller` - I can access the `Things` just fine in my edit, but I want to sort them differently (not over their ID), for example `Things.pos`

Whats the best practice here? I tried it with

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Thing' => array(
            'order' => 'Thing.pos DESC'
        )
    );
```

But nothing changed. Any idea?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Overread the Documentation. Sorry!

Anyways, If someone looks for an answer, here it is:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#sorting-contained-associations

**edit:**

> When loading HasMany and BelongsToMany associations, you can use the
>   sort option to sort the data in those associations:
>
> ```
> $query->contain([
>     'Comments' => [
>         'sort' => ['Comment.created' => 'DESC']
>     ]
> ]);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined some custom finder methods in your associated table, you can use them inside **contain()**. For your case you can solve this like below:

```
$query->contain([
        'Comments' => function ($q) {
           return $q->order(['created'=>'DESC']);
        }
    ]);
```